# Cross[] of a List of Vectors

Tags: list-manipulation, arguments, vector

Say I have some function `f[n]` that outputs a list of `n` vectors of length `n+1`. I want to take the `Cross[]` of all elements of that list:

```
Cross[f[n][[1]],f[n][[2]]...f[n][[n]]]
```

How do I automize this to take `f[n]` as an input? Previously I've just been copying and pasting the thing and deleting the inner and outer `{}` brackets.

Comment: Have you tried `Cross[Sequence@@f[n]]`?

Comment: Nope, because I literally didn't know about it. Works a charm; thanks!

Comment: try also `Cross @@ f[n]`

Comment: Alright, it worked for Cross. What about calling up a list of lists for integration bounds?

Comment: @KenRobbins as creidhne showed you, you can write `Integrate[fun, Sequence@@listOfLists]`.